# Create a Windows (XP) installer on a Linux machine?

Tags: windows, linux, installation

I need to create an installer for my software for Windows XP and newer. Is there any mechanism to do that on a Linux machine alone? (I'm running ubuntu, but I'd guess is not a show stopper).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It is hard to decide which I decide to mark as the correct answer. I think I go for NSIS, as it looks to be provided by my linux system. Free / Nonfree is not an issue here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is a free and open source installer system that allows you to create native Windows installers.

It uses ascript files to define all aspects of the setup procedure and with a compiler you generate the resulting setup package. You can find the sources [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/). The Installer system runs on Windows and POSIX compliant systems. There is also an [Eclipse plugin](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) available.

The Nullsoft installer is widely used for open source projects and even commercial products.

**UPDATE:** There is a new alpha release on December 24, 2013, so as of late 2013 this project is still active.

**UPDATE 2:** Beginning of April 2016 a new version 2.51 was released together with a release candidate for NSIS 3.0.

Comment: ...and this answer is from 2010. But if you look at the download stats at sourceforge it still quite heavy in use.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/).  It's a free, open source installer that is cross platform and can easily do what you want.  I have many users who build strictly for Windows but use Linux as their build platforms.

InstallJammer can build any of its supported platforms from any other platform, so it should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Active development of InstallJammer has been discontinued

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX. Could not find an installkit for your platform 'MacOS-X'.

Answer (score 1):

Flexera Software (makers of InstallShield) have a cross-platform installation authoring utility called InstallAnywhere:

http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm

> From a single project file and build
>   environment, InstallAnywhere enables
>   developers to create reliable
>   installations for the broadest range
>   of current platforms including
>   Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, AIX
>   , HP-UX, and IBM iSeries.

---

> InstallAnywhere runs on the latest
>   versions of these operating systems,
>   fully updated with the most recent
>   patches and service packs:
>
> •Windows 7 (32-bit x86) •Windows Vista
>   •Windows XP •Windows 2000 •Mac OS X
>   10.4, 10.5, and 10.6 with Java 1.6 •Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 and 5
>   (32-bit x86) •SUSE Linux 9, 10, and
>   11.2 (32-bit x86) •Ubuntu 9.10 (32-bit x86) •Solaris Solaris 9 and 10 (SPARC)
>   •HP-UX 11i (PA-RISC) •AIX 5.2, 5.3,
>   and 6.1 (Power/PowerPC)

Comment: Am I right that this software is rather costly? I can see its advantages, and I don't mind paying for it, but later...

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is costly. Of course they'll say "you get what you pay for", but ultimately you'll have to make that decision.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Our software [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) also allows building Windows installers from Linux You can do so from the command line to make it easier to integrate with nightly builds, ANT, etc.